# Bad encoding while insert mysqli record using php prepared statment

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to insert some Persian words as `mysql` data in `php` using `prepared statments`.
this is my `php` code:

```
$mysqliObj = new mysqli(HOST, USER_NAME, PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

mysqli_query($connection, "SET NAMES utf-8");
$stmt = $mysqliObj->prepare("INSERT INTO slideshow (slide_url, slide_title, slide_comment) VALUES (? , ? , ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $val1, $val2, $val3);
$val1 = $slidePathName;
$val2 = $_POST['title'];
$val3 = $_POST['comment'];
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$stmt->close();
```

insertion works great but in `phpMyAdmin` shows like `Ø¢Ù…ÙˆØ²Ø´ Ø§Ù†Ø¯Ø±ÙˆÛŒØ¯ Ù¾Ø§ÛŒÙ‡`
after search I found this line:

```
mysqli_query($connection, "SET NAMES utf-8");
```

and set `php` header like this:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

and in html :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

but still have a problem to encoding.
any idea would help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The charset is called `utf8` in MySQL, not `utf-8`. Preferably, if your version is new enough, use `utf8mb4` for full UTF-8 compatibility. Also preferably, use the `mysqli_set_charset` function, not a `SET NAMES` query.

Answer (score 1):

Use this, in your query.

```
$mysqliObj->set_charset("utf8");
```